# How can you solve $r^2v^{\prime\prime} + (n-1)rv^\prime + r^2v=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Let $n\ge 2$ be an integer. I am trying to solve the ODE
$$
r^2v^{\prime\prime}(r) + (n-1)rv^\prime(r) + r^2v(r)=0.
$$
This arises when attempting to find a fundamental solution for $\Delta + c$ where $c>0$.
I know that the solution involves Bessel functions, but I am having a hard time finding an appropriate transform. Any advice or references on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify what is constant and what depends on what. Specifically is $r$ constant ? Do we have $v(r)$ ?

Comment: @zwim yes it's v(r) since I am looking for a radial solution! I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v(r)=r^{a} y(r)$. Taking the derivatives and then substituting into your equation, we see that choosing $a=1-\frac{n}{2}$ leads to Bessel's equation for $y(r)$. The index of the solutions $Y_\alpha(r)$ and $J_\alpha(r)$ ends up being given by $\alpha^2=(1-\frac{n}{2})^2$.

Comment: I see. How do you come up with $v(r) = r^ay(r)$. Any reasoning behind this choice?

Comment: What I tried, in order: $r=a x$ together with $v =by$. Not useful. Then $v=r^a y$. If that didn't work I'd try $v=r^a y$ together with $x=r^b$. Usually, those are sufficient. In principle, you could consider the more general $v=f(r) y$ and $x=g(r)$, and choose $f$ and $g$ to simplify the resulting expression.

Choices were not motivated by the particular equation, but rather as a heuristic procedure.

Comment: Thank you! I tried $x = g(r)$ but for some reason didn't consider the second option $v = f(r)y$.